# Is there a way to predict how long GParted will take to resize a partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am constantly running out of space in my root (/) partition, which often makes it impossible to update packages and so I need to change it. Here is my current partitions (sorry, no way to un-Germanize this):

[image: Current partition layout]

I would like to shrink my /home partition, free up space this way and add it to the root partition. The harddrive is an SSD drive. Since I need this computer for work basically every day, I am wondering if there is anyway to judge how long this could take? So I can plan better when to do it.

Comment: Why do you have a 60 gig swap partition? Although your root partition has the minimum recommended 25 gig it is now a good idea to make it close to 50 or more as that is where snaps are stored. From the picture I can not tell where your home and root partitions are located. As for how long it takes no one can tell you that but it should not take very long.

Comment: @David, swap size is also recommended size (double my physical RAM - although now that I check this rule, it seems to be for smaller RAM sizes). And yes, snaps sizes seems to be the main culprit for having issues with root partition size. The partitions in the list view correspond to the partitions in the visual overview on top. First item in list is left-most, second item is the next one to the right and so on. So essentially (Windows aside) the order is root, swap, home. I guess, my main question is if re-partitioning actually needs physical changes or is just allocating space "virtually".

Comment: Yes up to 8 gig use double is the rule I have always known and used. If you have over 30 gig of ram as you appear to why any swap space?

Comment: @passwordispassword nah. we nowadays use a swapfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I need this computer for work basically every day, I am wondering if there is anyway to judge how long this could take? So I can plan better when to do it.

Nope.

It depends on a couple of questions and the one that is going to take the most of the time needed is: how much data needs to be moved? And that is basically impossible to answer.

> I am constantly running out of space in my root (/) partition.

20Gb for a desktop should be more than enough. 2 things that could fill up `/` and that can be avoided:

- /var/log/

  Check if there is a log file that keeps increasing quickly. If so check the error and fix it. clean out the log file using `> /var/log/{file}`
- snaps

  Probably best to store those outside of `/`.

> swap size is also recommended size (double my physical RAM - although now that I check that again, this rule seems to be mostly for smaller RAM sizes).

No. That was in the old days. We now use a swapfile. It would be best to remove that swap partition, switch to a swapfile and add the extra space to `/`. It will be a lot quicker then resizing `/home`.

Comment: Yep, it's mostly snaps fault. But if I understand correctly, there is (currently) no easy way of moving the snaps outside of `/`? Thank you for the suggestion of moving to swapfile and giving that space to `/`partition, that seems to be a very reasonable solution.

Comment: @passwordispassword I have deleted all snaps myself. Only going to use those if they are kept out of /

Comment: Please rephrase "outside of `/`" as "on a filesystem other than where `/` is mounted" or similar. There is really no such thing as "outside of `/`".

Answer (score 1):

On a NVMe drive in my quite recent laptop it is pretty fast - about 250 MB/s

[image]